# minimal number of relations in nonabelian dihedral groups of order a power of 2

Tags: group-theory

In my recent minimal number of relations r question for the symmetric group 
of degree 3, it was demonstrated that r = 2.  What is r in general for nonabelian dihedral groups of order a power of 2?  Or more specifically is r = 2 or 3 for the dihedral group of order 8?  And if r = 2, what are the defining relations and how does one show that we actually get the dihedral group of order 8 from these relations?  My motivation in asking this question is that by the sharpened Golod/Shafarevich inequality, we know that for finite p-groups (actually for nilotent groups) that r > (d/2) squared where d is the minimal number of generators of the group.  I would like to know if for d large enough if this inequality can possibly be sharpened further, to r > (d/2) squared + 1. And in particular, for d = 4 are there any known examples as above with r = 5?

Answer (score 1):

$r=3$ for dihedral groups of order divisible by $4$. The standard presentation shows that $r \le 3$, and the fact that the Schur multiplier is nontrivial (it has order $2$) shows that $r-d \ge 1$, so $r=3$.

Comment: This is very helpful, Derek--and to pursue this, do you know of any finite p-groups or specifically 2-groups for which either d = 2 and r = 2, d = 3 and r = 3, or d = 4 and r = 5?  This would show that the sharpened Golod/Shafarevich inequality is indeed "sharp" in these cases.